# Could not resolve host: on WSL ubuntu after trying to install anything

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to set up nvim but this is a general problem with anything I attempt to install.
As an example

```
root@DESKTOP-NAME:~# git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim\
 ~/.loc>  ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim

Cloning into '/root/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

I looked around for fixes but my `/etc/hosts` has the lines shown in some answers. I tried to delete and then restart the terminal but it did not automatically re add the file, so I added it in manually with the same two lines. I am using WSL with Ubuntu. I also have no VPNs or Proxys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows - could not resolve host using VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1145717/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-could-not-resolve-host-using-vpn)

Comment: @Ramhound I followed those steps and added the IPs listed to the file but it did not work I still get the same error, it resets every time you restart the terminal I think. Also, I am not using a VPN

Comment: Does not really matter you are not using a VPN the error is the exact same error, which suggest, the resolution is identical

Comment: still didn't fix error ,all of the solutions i have seen havent fixed @Ramhound

Comment: @Ramhound That's a fairly generic error that will occur when there is *any* networking issue in WSL.  That doesn't indicate a duplicate by any means.  It may be a duplicate of another question (which we'll only find through troubleshooting), but it's almost certainly not a duplicate of question where the problem specifically occurred when connected to a VPN.

Comment: @Hydrolox First we need to figure out if this is truly a DNS issue or a more low-level networking issue.  Can you `ping 8.8.8.8` from inside WSL?  If so, then yes, we're probably looking at something DNS/`resolv.conf` (or possibly `apt`) related.  But if you don't get a response there, then we need to look at more generic networking issues in WSL.  Thanks!